# pergunta extremamente basica estou começando respondam rapido

Tags: javascript

Monte a estrutura HTML e arquivo CSS da página com layout abaixo. usando ids ou classes.

[image: monte a estrutura html e arquivo css da página com layout abaixo]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Segue os códigos:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header><div class="cabecalho"></div></header>
<main>
    <section>
        <div class="conteudo"></div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="conteudos">
            <div class="esquerdo"></div>
            <div class="direito"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="rodape">
        <div></div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Agora o CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.cabecalho{
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: burlywood;

}

.conteudo{
    width: auto;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 136, 35);

}

.conteudos{
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
}

.esquerdo{
    width: 40%;
    height: 620px;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.direito{
    width: 60%;
    height: 620px;
    background-color: rgb(253, 72, 40);
}

.rodape{
    width: auto;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: grey;

}
```